# How to preview a page instead of a category?

Tags: pages

Is it possible to make the code below preview a page instead of a latest category post?

```
<div class="one_third_last">
  <h2>Gift Vouchers</h2>
  <div class="entry">   
<?php
//The Query
query_posts('posts_per_page=1&cat=7');
//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></small></a>
  <p><a rel="bookmark" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt());?></a></p> 
</div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif;
//Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
    </div>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try and change this line:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=1&cat=7');
```

to:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=1&page_id=17');
```

or:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=1&pagename=page-slug');
```

(enter the actual page ID or page slug into the respective space)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: No need for the `posts_per_page` argument, i very much doubt you'll get more than one result when querying by a specific page ID... ;)